# Oracle select min row from multiple results

Tags: sql, oracle

I have been trying to solve this for a while now, any help would be greatly appreciated.

I have tables:

```
distributor(distributor_name, distributor_id)
distributed(price, movie_id, distributor_id)
movie(title, movie_id)
```

Each distributor has multiple records for movies at different prices.

I am trying to select the minimum price for a particular movie and from what distributor

so far I have tried:

```
select min(Price), Distributor from
(select m.distributor_name as Distributor, d.price from 
distributors m, distributed d, movies mo
where
mo.title = 'Movie Name' and mo.movie_id = d.movie_id and d.distributor_id = m.distributor_id)
group by Distributor;
```

Which returns the minimum price for each distributor.

If I run:

```
select min(Price)
(select m.distributor_name as Distributor, d.price from 
distributors m, distributed d, movies mo
where
mo.title = 'Movie Name' and mo.movie_id = d.movie_id and d.distributor_id = m.distributor_id);
```

It gives just the lowest price of that particular movie.

How can I get the name of the distributor for the lowest price?

Comment: How did you edit it to look like that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Depending on your version of Oracle, you can use `row_number()`:

```
select price, distributor
from
(
  select d.price, 
    m.distributor_name as Distributor,
    row_number() over(order by d.price) rn
  from distributors m
  inner join distributed d
    on d.distributor_id = m.distributor_id
  inner join movies mo 
    on mo.movie_id = d.movie_id 
  where mo.title = 'Movie Name' 
) src
where rn = 1;
```

See [SQL Fiddle with Demo](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!4/52d13/3)

If you wanted to expand on this and get the lowest price for any movie, then you could partition the data by movie title:

```
select price, distributor
from
(
  select d.price, 
    m.distributor_name as Distributor,
    row_number() over(partition by mo.title order by d.price) rn
  from distributors m
  inner join distributed d
    on d.distributor_id = m.distributor_id
  inner join movies mo 
    on mo.movie_id = d.movie_id 
) src
where rn = 1;
```

Comment: That still gives the same list that I got before with multiple entries ex: Best Buy 179.99, Amazon 169.99, Blockbuster 19.99, I need just blockbuster and 19.99

Comment: @ssgtob1 are you using the line `row_number() over(order by d.price)`, I edited it and it is now different from my original answer.

Comment: How do you post questions with the sql code looking the right way?

Comment: @ssgtob1 happy to help -- here is a handy link to how to markdown the code in your posts -- http://stackoverflow.com/editing-help